# "Timed out" when using openvpn-api for Python

Tags: python, vpn, openvpn

I don't know if anyone here have ever used **openvpn-api** for Python, I couldn't find any troubleshooting about it.

So here is my problem... I'm trying to connect to my VPN management interface, using this **openvpn-api**. But the connection never happens, I get "timed out" error.

**This is my code:**

```
from openvpn_api import VPN

v = VPN('192.168.x.x', 10000)

with v.connect():
    print(v.release)
```

**And this is the error I get:**

```
openvpn_api.util.errors.ConnectError: timed out
```

When I do a **nmap** to the host, I get this:

```
$ nmap -p 10000 192.168.x.x

Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-11-19 11:02 -03
Nmap scan report for 192.168.x.x
Host is up (0.00087s latency).

PORT      STATE SERVICE
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt
```

The web interface uses an auto-signed SSL certificate, if that's relevant.

Anyone could help me?